# javascript - two buttons to open 2 iframes respectively

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Good afternoon,
I'm using two buttons on my site, each opens a different `iframe`.
The problem is that after clicking to open one, the other does not open simultaneously when clicking the other `iframe` button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#load').click(function() {
    if (!$('#iframe').length) {
      $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" width="100%" height="700px;"></iframe>');
    }
  });
});


$(function() {
  $('#load2').click(function() {
    if (!$('#iframe').length) {
      $('#iframeHolder2').html('<iframe id="iframe" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://assets.wordpress.envato-static.com/uploads/2017/08/tropical-PS53BSA.jpg" width="100%" height="300px;"></iframe>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<center>
  <a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;" class="hashtagsocial" id="load">PODCASTS</a>&nbsp;
  <a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;" class="hashtagsocial" id="load2">SCHEDULE</a>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="iframeHolder"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="iframeHolder2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's exactly what `if(!$('#iframe').length)` is preventing in both of your buttons.  When you append your new HTML to the page, it includes an element with `id="iframe"`.  So the next time you run that `if` statement, `.length` is greater than `0` so the check is `false` and the `if` block does not execute.

Without that `if`, you can open both:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(){ 
        $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" width="100%" height="700px;"></iframe>');
    });   
});
        
        
$(function(){
    $('#load2').click(function(){ 
        $('#iframeHolder2').html('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://assets.wordpress.envato-static.com/uploads/2017/08/tropical-PS53BSA.jpg" width="100%" height="300px;"></iframe>');
    });   
});
```

```html
<center><a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;" class="hashtagsocial" id="load">PODCASTS</a>&nbsp;<a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;" class="hashtagsocial" id="load2">SCHEDULE</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="iframeHolder"></div>  
<br>
<br>
<div id="iframeHolder2"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** I *also* removed the `id="iframe"` from the appended HTML, since you don't want to append two elements with the same `id` to the page.  If you need those elements to have IDs, they'll have to be unique.

---

*If*, on the other hand, you want to be able to *switch* between the two then you would want to put them in a single container rather than in their own containers:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(){ 
        $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" width="100%" height="700px;"></iframe>');
    });   
});
        
        
$(function(){
    $('#load2').click(function(){ 
        $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://assets.wordpress.envato-static.com/uploads/2017/08/tropical-PS53BSA.jpg" width="100%" height="300px;"></iframe>');
    });   
});
```

```html
<center><a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;" class="hashtagsocial" id="load">PODCASTS</a>&nbsp;<a style="background-color: rgb(98,124,169,0.8); color: white; cursor: pointer;" class="hashtagsocial" id="load2">SCHEDULE</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="iframeHolder"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note also that using 2 `document.ready` handlers is redundant.  You don't need that much ceremony for each click handler, just create them both:

```
$(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(){ 
        $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg" width="100%" height="700px;"></iframe>');
    });   

    $('#load2').click(function(){ 
        $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:0px;" src="https://assets.wordpress.envato-static.com/uploads/2017/08/tropical-PS53BSA.jpg" width="100%" height="300px;"></iframe>');
    });   
});
```